# Problem creating Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1064

I have written the below mentioned script in MySQL to create Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddBranch`(
IN `inCompanyCode` char(3), 
IN `inBranchCode` varchar(6), 
IN `inBankBranch` varchar(40)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE branchExists TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT Count(*) INTO branchExists FROM branches WHERE CompanyCode = inCompanyCode AND BranchCode = inBranchCode;
    IF branchExists = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO branches VALUES (inCompanyCode, inBranchCode, inBankBranch);
    ELSE
        UPDATE branches SET Branch = inBankBranch
        WHERE CompanyCode = inCompanyCode AND BranchCode = inBranchCode;
    END IF;
END;
```

While running the query, the error message displayed is:

***1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7***

I have even tried `DECLARE branchExists TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;` but the problem persists.

What is wrong with line 7?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to redefine Delimiter to something else (eg: `$$`), instead of (`;`).
- Also as a safety measure, check if the same name procedure already exists or not (`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS`)
- At the end, redefine the `DELIMITER` to `;`

Change the stored procedure to as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AddBranch`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `AddBranch`(
IN `inCompanyCode` char(3), 
IN `inBranchCode` varchar(6), 
IN `inBankBranch` varchar(40)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE branchExists TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT Count(*) INTO branchExists FROM branches WHERE CompanyCode = inCompanyCode AND BranchCode = inBranchCode;
    IF branchExists = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO branches VALUES (inCompanyCode, inBranchCode, inBankBranch);
    ELSE
        UPDATE branches SET Branch = inBankBranch
        WHERE CompanyCode = inCompanyCode AND BranchCode = inBranchCode;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But could you please tell me why do we need `$$`?

Comment: @kush.impetus `$$` is just an example. It could be anything like `??`. To create a stored procedure, we have to run the above query. And, we want this whole statement to get stored as a SP, together. But, if we have `;` in between, MySQL parser will try to execute statements individually, which wont make any sense (instead of storing it as a SP). So, we set the delimiter to something else, so that it gets stored properly.